# JSHint expected an assignment or function call for multiple assignment

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint

I was linting some existing JavaScript and I get the error message `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.` for the following.

```
var k, i;
k = 0, i = -1;
```

The assignment appears to happen correctly, so what is wrong with this that it causes the lint warning?

---

For a bigger picture; here is what the beginning of the function looks like that leads up to this, if it is helpful.

```
var subgroups = {},
    groupSums = [],
    groupIndex = d3.range(n),
    subgroupIndex = [],
    k,
    x,
    x0,
    i,
    j;

chords = [];
groups = [];

// Compute the sum.
k = 0, i = -1; while (++i < n) {
  x = 0, j = -1; while (++j < n) {
    x += matrix[i][j];
  }
  groupSums.push(x);
  subgroupIndex.push(d3.range(n));
  k += x;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code too?

Comment: I've added additional code above.  This is the very beginning of a function; the variables are defined ahead of time and should hoist to my function scope appropriately.

Comment: Please clarify jshint vs. jslint, I guess the former?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comma operator creates an **expression**. It's an operator that evaluates the two things on the left and right, then yields as its value the one on the right. Even if the things separated by the commas are assignments, JS still views the comma operator as creating an expression.

JSLint and JSHint don't like expressions that are just sitting there not doing anything, such as

```
0 !== 1;
```

To the linters,

```
k = 0, i = 1;
```

is a forlorn expression, not doing anything.

In your particular case, it could be easier to just do

```
for (k = 0, i = -1; ++i < n; ) {
```

and be done with it, although personally I'd write

```
for (k = 0, i = 0; i < n; i++) {
```

As you probably already know, you can turn this off (examples for JSHint):

```
/*jshint -W030*/
/*jshint expr:true*/
```

Comment: Gotcha; this was is what I'm looking for.  Trying to understand how JavaScript was handling this and understand the underlying reason it is bad form.  Thanks. This is an existing code base that I'm just beginning to look at so I don't want to disable these in the linter; just like to understand the "why" of things when I run into something I don't recognize.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Use the `var` keyword and the error goes away.</strike> (Turns out the OP *did* use the `var` keyword.)

Rolling two separate assignments into one expression with the comma operator like this:

```
k = 0, i = -1;
```

is legally possible in JavaScript. It is not considered good style, though. Simply use the semicolon as a statement separator:

```
k = 0; i = -1;
```

The comma operator, as per the MDN:

> You can use the comma operator when you want to include multiple expressions in a location that requires a single expression.

Your situation does not fit the bill. Clever use of language features is considered harmful. Try not to do clever stuff outside of code golf competitions.

Comment: I've modified the code snippet slightly above to show that the variables were declared ahead of time.

Comment: If you want to suppress the warning use `"expr": true,` in your .jshintrc file.

Comment: Torazaburo explained well why this works & is bad style which is really what I was trying to understand here, but this was helpful as well so did up vote.  Thanks.

Comment: There are other syntactically valid JS snippets that jshint does not like: try `while (var i = fooFunc(arg)) { /* ... */ }`. This is legal JS, covered by the spec and everything, but it triggers a flurry of errors for its bad style.

Answer (score -2):

You should do it like this:

```
k = 0;
i = -1;
```

Comment: I understand that this will get rid of the message; I'm trying to understand the reason why this is considered a bad practice or why it is flagged in the first case.